# Algorithm for shorthest path that contains exactly n edges of weight 2 in 1,2-weighted directed graph

Tags: shortest-path, network-flow, dijkstras-algorithm

I am trying to find an efficient algorithm for the following problem:

Input:

- weighted directed graph **G=(V, E)** in which all edges are weigthed either 1 or 2
- **s,t** ∈ V
- **n** ∈ N

Output

- shortest path from **s** to **t** that contains exactly **n** edges of weight 2

I have been experimenting with different modifications of Bellman-Ford, Dijkstra and even max-flow with no luck.

Is there an efficient algorithm for solving this?

Answer (score 2):

When all edges have weight 2 and $n = |V|$ the problem is equivalent to [longest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) which is NP-complete. So unless P = NP, there is no efficient algorithm for solving the problem.